# Find value of $t$ between the difference of 3D vectors.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Hint: The distance between $2$ vectors equals the magnitude of their difference.

What is the value of $t$ for which the vector
$\mathbf v = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -3 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 7 \\ 5 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}t$
is closest to
$\mathbf a = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}?$

Using the hint, my idea is to find the difference of **v** and **a** and find the magnitude of the value. From there, I can use regular algebraic forms to solve for $t$.

This is what I have done so far:

$\mathbf v$ can be simplified down to $\begin{pmatrix} 2+7t \\ -3+5t \\ -3-t \end{pmatrix}$.

The difference of $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf a$ is: $\begin{pmatrix} 2+7t \\ -3+5t \\ -3-t \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -2+7t \\ -7+5t \\ -8-t \end{pmatrix}$.

Am I solving this problem correctly so far, and do I have the right idea as to how to properly approach this problem?

Thanks.

--Grace

Comment: So far, so good. You recall how to get the magnitude of the resultant? Also, do you recall how to minimise that?

Comment: You should minimize $||v-a||^2 = (7t-2)^2 + (5t-7) + (-t-8)^2$.

Comment: I changed $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} 2+7t \\ -3+5t \\ -3-t \end{pmatrix}$ - $\displaystyle\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}$ to $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} 2+7t \\ -3+5t \\ -3-t \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}$.  The minus sign should be a minus sign, not a hyphen.  Put the hyphen inside the MathJax tags and you'll see a minus sign rather than a hyphen. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: As Terra Hyde and Michael Galuza suggested, you need to decide what [b]you[/b] mean by "minimizing" a vector since there is no "linear order" defined on vectors.  Do you mean "minimize the magnitude"?

Comment: @Grace, expand and get quadratic function, which is simple for minimizing. I missed square in second term in my previous comment, of course

Comment: @MichaelGaluza: The quadratic function is $75t^2-82t+117$. Would I just use the quadratic formula then to find $t$?

Comment: @Grace, no, you should minimize it. For example, take derivative and nullify: $150t-82=0$

Comment: @Grace: have you tried using scalar product? This type of question is more easily solved in this way

Comment: @Grace: take your expression for the vector $v-a$ and use scalar product to multiply this with the direction vector of the line, i.e. $(7, 5, -1)$ and set this equal to zero to find the value of $t$. The reason for this is that, at the point on the line closest to $a$, the vector $v-a$ is perpendicular to the direction of the line.

Comment: @DavidQuinn: Thanks so much! I figured out the answer! :)

Comment: @Grace: you're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's long for comment. We should minimize
$$
|v−a|^2=(7t−2)^2+(5t−7)^2+(−t−8)^2=75t^2-82t+117
$$
(actually, it's distance from point $\vec a$ to the line $\vec v$). Without derivatives we can write
$$
75t^2-82t+117=75\left(t^2-\frac{82}{75}t + \frac{41^2}{75^2}\right) + \left(117 - \frac{41^2}{75}\right) =\\= 75\left(t-\frac{41}{75}\right)^2 + \left(117 - \frac{41^2}{75}\right) \ge 117 - \frac{41^2}{75}$$

Answer (score 0):

For a straight line given by $x=b+\lambda u$ and a point $ a$ consider the area of the parallelogram spanned by $u$ and $a-b$.  Its area is the length of the cross product of those two.  Divide that area by the length of $u$ to get the height of the parallelogram which is the distance from $a$ to the straight line.